# do you need to reboot after tweaking linux tcp settings?

Tags: linux, tcp, optimization

I'm wondering if you need to reboot if you make changes to settings related to linux tcp such as tcp_window_scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, execute `sysctl -p` to make new settings take effect.